# How can I completely reinstall mysql?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, mysql

I had to reboot in the middle of a large data import. I only have one mysql database, which has now been corrupted.

How can I completely remove mysql and reinstall it? I've tried `apt-get purge mysql-server`, then removing `/var/lib/mysql/*` and reinstalling, but `apt-get` does not prompt me for a root name and password nor does it recreate the `/var/lib/mysql` files. How can I reinstall?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client-<version>
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /etc/mysql*
```

Then you can reinstall in full.

Comment: thanks! also had to add the version to mysql-server-<version>

Comment: +1 for mentioning removal of /var/lib/mysql . Keeping that can disallow you performing clean install because it seems it keeps some information about the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to execute this:

```
sudo mysqld --initialize
```

Comment: mysqld 5.6.30 doesn't seem to have this switch.