# Install MySQL Server with prompt for initial password

Tags: linux-mint, mysql

On Linux Mint, I installed MySQL Server and opted to use a blank password.

This means I can't login to phpMyAdmin, as blank passwords are not accepted.

I can't reset the root MySQL password either, as the blank password is not accepted when running:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p password newpass
```

I can't run `mysql_secure_installation` either as the blank password is not accepted there too.

If I use Software Manager to remove MySQL Server, and then install MySQL Server again, I am not prompted to set up a password.

If I run:

```
apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client-<version>
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /etc/mysql*
```

from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27558/212697), I am still not prompted for a password on installing MySQL Server again.

Help appreciated.

**Update**

When I run `mysql -uroot` I receive:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

When I run `service mysql start` I receive:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status mysql.service` and `journalctl -xe`?

Answer (score 2):

Login passwordlessly to MySQL via

```
mysql -uroot
```

Then change the root password via

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('myp4ssw0rd');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks dr01, see the update to my question please.