# Which program creates the /etc/mysql directory and its contents?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I was trying to install mysql-server and while trying to set a password I messed up the debian.cnf file and then deleted /etc/mysql hoping that `dpkg-reconfigure` would recreate it.

Now dpkg-reconfigure is giving an error regarding missing cnf files in /etc/mysql

Tried reinstalling `mysql-server` itself but the post-install script is giving errors.

I've also tried reinstalling `libmysqldev, libmysql20 and mysql-common`. No luck.

Which package should I reinstall to create the /etc/mysql and its contents

If I remember correctly the directory contains my.cnf, debian.cnf, conf.d and a couple other files. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate question since https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27549/how-can-i-completely-reinstall-mysql?rq=1 has the answer that I'm looking for.

Comment: You might try running `dpkg -S /etc/mysql` (although this may miss files that are created on the fly by pre/post install scripts, rather than being provided by a package directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `/etc/mysql` are created by `mysql-server-5.7`’s `postinst` (replace “5.7” with whichever version you have). You should try running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
```

and fixing any errors which occur then.

[How can I completely reinstall mysql?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27549/86440) explains how to reinstall MySQL completely. Do note however that deleting `/var/lib/mysql` will delete any database which you’ve created.